# Preventing runaway SQL in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

in an existing application there are several dynamically generated SQL statements that are being executed. Some of those are very slow in performance and block the UI.

Without changing the code that generates the SQL I was wondering if there is a way to prematurely stop an Oracle/SQL statement that exceeds
a) an execution time threshold
b) number of result rows

While b) sounds easy, it is not easy in the application infrastructure I am dealing with, because I do not get a recordset back that I can iterate over as the SQL is being executed. I guess in some ways a huge number of result rows would eventually trigger the time threshold.

I read something about using the Oracle Resource Manager, but I wasn't sure if that can address a) and b) and if that is the easiest way to solve this. I was hoping there are session/connection options that would help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a profile to limit the CPU time on a single SQL call.  Assign that profile to the application user.

```
--Create profile that limits CPU per call to 1 second.
create profile temp_profile limit cpu_per_call 100;

--Create user, assign profile.
create user profile_test_user identified by "asDF1234!";
alter user profile_test_user profile temp_profile;
grant connect to profile_test_user;
```

That user will get errors like this:

```
PROFILE_TEST_USER@someDB> select count(*) from user_objects;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

PROFILE_TEST_USER@someDB> select count(*) from all_objects;
select count(*) from all_objects
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02393: exceeded call limit on CPU usage
```

In general this approach should be a last resort.  It's usually better to spend time tuning queries and databases.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Resource Consumer groups. You can limit things like CPU time to sessions/queries for specfic groups of users.

This would be a database solution, not an application one - so it would work for that user regardless of how they are logged into the database.